# SharePoint Lists Web Service Proxy Unauthorized Error

Tags: development, list, web-services, authentication

I am trying to get data from a SharePoint list by using SharePoint Lists Web service. I have a MS Office Excel Add-In with a WPF User Control inside it. I used the following code to make a proxy object to the Lists Web Service. And use that proxy to obtain list 'Products'.

```
        1. SPListWS.Lists myListReadProxy = new SPListWS.Lists();
        2. myListReadProxy.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
        3. myListReadProxy.Url = "http://sp2010:4321/_vti_bin/Lists.asmx";
        4. 
        5. XmlNode myNode = myListReadProxy.GetList("Products");
```

Visual Studio come up with an error at the line 5, saying that

> The request failed with HTTP status 401: Unauthorized.

I changed the code as following to provide credentials explicitly. But the same error arises.
         `myListReadProxy.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("myusername", "mypassword");`

And I checked the permission for the web service and the List. I have full permission.
When I handle the Web Exception is gives the status as 'Protocol Error'.

Can you please help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured out what was wrong with my project. Actually when I add a web reference for my project, I clicked on Add Service Reference and searched for services in my local machine. So I found my Lists web service with url like this `http://localhost:4321/_vti_bin/Lists.asmx` instead of `http://sp2010:4321/_vti_bin/Lists.asmx` . And when I set the URL for my proxy object I added the url as `http://sp2010:4321/_vti_bin/Lists.asmx` in  the code section.

When I change my web reference to use the explicit server name everything worked fine. Hope somebody would find this helpful if they faced to a similar situation.